# Recontructing a data.frame with gaps filled

Tags: r

I'm very new to R and am working on a project that I need help with.

I have a CSV file with a year's worth of data. There are some gaps in the time series, however, and I need it to be spaced evenly every half hour (48 lines per day times 365 days in the year would make 17520 lines of data in a full year). The gaps range from 1 half hour to several days. Rows do not exist for these missing timestamps. So, I've used a few other forum posts to help me make a script that will import the CSV into R, make the timestamp column the correct length by creating rows, and then match the data to the new timestamp column.

However, I have about 3 dozen columns of data to match to the new timestamp, and the way I'm doing it now is terribly inefficient. As of now, a data.frame (newdata4) exists with the correct timestamps. Then, I add a new column to that frame with the original data from the missing4 data.frame:

```
newdata4 <- as.data.frame(timestamp_corr)
newdata4$PAR_in_Avg <- missing4$PAR_in_Avg[pmatch(newdata4$timestamp_corr, missing4$timestamp)] # add data where there was an original timestamp
newdata4$PAR_in_Avg[is.na(newdata4$PAR_in_Avg)] <- -9999 # replace NAs with -9999
```

In this example, PAR_in_Avg is a column from the original CSV file. This works very well. But, to get all the columns into the newdata4, I have repeated these lines over and over:

```
newdata4$PAR_in_Avg <- missing4$PAR_in_Avg[pmatch(newdata4$timestamp_corr, missing4$timestamp)] # add data where there was an original timestamp
newdata4$PAR_in_Avg[is.na(newdata4$PAR_in_Avg)] <- -9999 # replace NAs with -9999
newdata4$PAR_out_Avg <- missing4$PAR_out_Avg[pmatch(newdata4$timestamp_corr, missing4$timestamp)] # add data where there was an original timestamp
newdata4$PAR_out_Avg[is.na(newdata4$PAR_out_Avg)] <- -9999 # replace NAs with -9999
newdata4$Rn_meas_Avg <- missing4$Rn_meas_Avg[pmatch(newdata4$timestamp_corr, missing4$timestamp)] # add data where there was an original timestamp
newdata4$Rn_meas_Avg[is.na(newdata4$Rn_meas_Avg)] <- -9999 # replace NAs with -9999
newdata4$PYRA_CMP3_Avg <- missing4$PYRA_CMP3_Avg[pmatch(newdata4$timestamp_corr, missing4$timestamp)] # add data where there was an original timestamp
newdata4$PYRA_CMP3_Avg[is.na(newdata4$PYRA_CMP3_Avg)] <- -9999 # replace NAs with -9999
newdata4$G_1_Avg <- missing4$G_1_Avg[pmatch(newdata4$timestamp_corr, missing4$timestamp)] # add data where there was an original timestamp
newdata4$G_1_Avg[is.na(newdata4$G_1_Avg)] <- -9999 # replace NAs with -9999
newdata4$G_2_Avg <- missing4$G_2_Avg[pmatch(newdata4$timestamp_corr, missing4$timestamp)] # add data where there was an original timestamp
newdata4$G_2_Avg[is.na(newdata4$G_2_Avg)] <- -9999 # replace NAs with -9999
newdata4$G_3_Avg <- missing4$G_3_Avg[pmatch(newdata4$timestamp_corr, missing4$timestamp)] # add data where there was an original timestamp
newdata4$G_3_Avg[is.na(newdata4$G_3_Avg)] <- -9999 # replace NAs with -9999
newdata4$G_4_Avg <- missing4$G_4_Avg[pmatch(newdata4$timestamp_corr, missing4$timestamp)] # add data where there was an original timestamp
newdata4$G_4_Avg[is.na(newdata4$G_4_Avg)] <- -9999 # replace NAs with -9999
```

This can't be sustainable, as I have to do this with other sites and other years (each with different column headings). Ideally, I would like R to read the first row of this CSV file to determine how many columns there are, and then add each of these back using pmatch once the new time series has been constructed.

I was able to merge the newdata4 data.frame and original missing4 data.frame, but doing so removed all the rows that had been just been created for the gaps.

Is there some simple way of putting the data back together that doesn't require such repetition?

Comment: It would be better if you show few lines of the dataset also.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
newdat <- data.frame(timestamp=with(dat, seq(min(timestamp),
                     max(timestamp), by='30 min')))

dat1 <- merge(dat, newdat, by='timestamp', all=TRUE)
indx <- setdiff(colnames(dat1), 'timestamp')
dat1[indx][is.na(dat1[indx])] <- -9999
head(dat1)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(timestamp= sort(sample(seq(as.POSIXct('1996-01-01'),
    length.out=50, by='30 min'),30, replace=FALSE)), value1=rnorm(30),
    value2=runif(30))
```